# como faço para exibir na tela o maior altura já lido?

Tags: c

```
int sexo = 1;
float altura;
int tm = 0, tf = 0, sm = 0, sf =0;   

printf ("O valor 0 encera o programa !!!\n");
    while (sexo!=0)
    {
        printf ("1-Masculino\t2-Feminino\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sexo);

        if (sexo == 1)
        {tm++;
        printf ("altura do Homen: \n");
        scanf ("%f", &altura);}

        if (sexo == 2)
        {tf++;
        printf ("Altura da Mulher: \n");
        scanf ("%f", &altura);}

        if (altura>0)
        altura=maior;
        {maior=altura}
    }

    printf ("Maior altura :%2.f",maior);
    printf ("Numero total de Homens: %d", tm);
    printf ("Numero total de Mulheres: %d", tf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa declarar inicialmente a variável `maior` como o valor 0, e após isso ir verificando se cada entrada do usuário é maior do que o valor previamente armazenado. Se for, armazene o novo valor na variável `maior`. O código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int sexo = 1;
    float altura, maior = 0;
    int tm = 0, tf = 0, sm = 0, sf =0;   

    printf ("O valor 0 encera o programa !!!\n");
    while (sexo!=0) {
        printf ("1-Masculino\t2-Feminino\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sexo);

        if (sexo == 1) {
            tm++;
            printf ("altura do Homen: \n");
            scanf ("%f", &altura);
        }

        if (sexo == 2) {
            tf++;
            printf ("Altura da Mulher: \n");
            scanf ("%f", &altura);
        }

        if (altura > maior) {
            maior = altura;
        }

    }
    printf ("Maior altura :%2.f",maior);
    printf ("Numero total de Homens: %d", tm);
    printf ("Numero total de Mulheres: %d", tf);
}
```

Para que você entenda melhor, aqui tem o código que verifica apenas o maior número inserido.

```
// Declaração das variáveis
float maior = 0, altura;
// Recebemos o valor de altura
scanf("%d", &altura);
// Se a altura informada for maior que a maior altura armazenada até então, armazene a nova altura
if(altura > maior) {
    maior = altura;
}
```

Comment: Obrigadão tava horas nisso

Comment: para imprimir a menor seria if (altura<menor){menor=altura;} ?

Comment: Não... Você teria que inicialmente, atribuir menor como o primeiro valor recebido na primeira iteração. A partir da segunda iteração você poderia fazer `if (altura<menor){menor=altura;}`